# How do I pass an enum value as a command parameter for button in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, command

I am having difficulties passing an enum value as a command parameter for a button in WPF.

**Here is my enum definition:**

```
namespace Foo.Foobar
{
    public enum PlanTypes : int
    {
        Undefined = -1,
        Previous = 0, 
        Current = 1,
        Future = 2
    }
}
```

**Here is my value converter:**

```
public class PlanTypeConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
  public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
  {
     return this;
  }

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      try
      {
          if (value == null)
          {
              return PlanTypes.Undefined;
          }

          int iPlanType = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
          return (PlanTypes)iPlanType;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           throw e;
       }
  }
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
      return Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
  }
}
```

**Here are snippets from my XAML definition:**

```
<UserControl x:Class=""
 ...
 xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:Foo.Foobar"
/>

<!-- Value Converters -->
<views:PlanTypeConverter x:Key="PlanTypeConvert"/>

<Button Content="Some Text"
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=DataContext.SelectPlanCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlanTypeConvert}, ConverterParameter={Binding {x:Static enums:PlanTypes.PreviousPlan}}}" />
```

The XAML compiler cannot seem to resolve the enum type: PreviousPlan.
At runtime VS throws an exception when trying to resolve this.

Is this the correct way to pass an enum value as a command parameter?
Do I really need to use a value converter to do this?

Thanks, JohnB

Comment: `CommandParameter="{x:Static enums:PlanTypes.Previous}"` should be enough

Comment: ASh: Spot on. Works perfectly. Thx